# Firebase - Using Collection, Sub Collection or Array?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm in the design stage of my App DB, running on Firebase.
I wonder what is the best approach to store my Data.
I know that Firebase only returns the first layer of the document unless you explicitly query for sub-collection And I want to reduce extra reads as much as possible to save $.

In short, my DB holds devices and each device can have messages (call-backs) that the server needs to send back to him, one at a time, in FIFO order.
The user sees the waiting call-backs when watching a device in the App.

My first thought was to hold a collection of messages for each device, but this approach will require two reads for each call-back in each device when the server wants to know what is the next call-back to send.

My second approach is to hold the call-back in array in each device document but I'm not sure if it is the right approach, sounds messy to me for some reason.

My third option is to hold a collection of call-backs with the deviceID field in each call-back. the drawback I see in this approach is that I need to perform some kind of "join" when viewing a device and his call-backs in the App, And the searching time for the next call-back is increasing, although still reasonable (log(n) time).

If we talk numbers theoretically the system can store tens of thousands of devices and each device can have 10-100 call-backs in line, and each call-back can be called every 15 seconds or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first thought was to hold a collection of messages for each device, but this approach will require two reads for each call-back in each device when the server wants to know what is the next call-back to send.

If you need to query the messages that correspond to a device, then storing them into a collection is a good option to go ahead with. This is because you can perform [simple and compound qureis](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

> My second approach is to hold the call-back in array in each device document but I'm not sure if it is the right approach, sounds messy to me for some reason.

If you only need to list them, and not query, then that's a really good idea in my opinion, but only if the size of the document can stay below the maximum limit. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much but as your array gets bigger, be careful about this limitation.

> My third option is to hold a collection of call-backs with deviceID field in each call-back. the drawback I see in this approach is that I need to perform some kind of "join" when viewing a device and his call-backs in the App, And the searching time for the next call-back is increasing, although still reasonable (log(n) time).

When talking again about collections, we are getting back to the first question. Remember, we are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. So it's up to you to decide if this approach it's best for you.

Always keep in mind that you are billed according to the number of documents a query returns.

Comment: "Always keep in mind that you are billed according to the number of documents a query returns."

So if I query one device and from his callbacks  collection I query the oldest one it's count as two?

I have to use the device Firebase id for such a query or I can do it also with field filtering?

Comment: Yes, you'll be billed with one read operation for each document that is returned by a query. For example, if you have a collection of 1000 documents, and your query only returns 10, you'll only have to pay 10 document reads. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes. Sounds like holding a sub-collection for each device fit for the queries I want to perform.

Comment: Yes, then you should go ahead with that.